# Python While loop to equal number

Tags: python, while-loop

Im trying to have users enter numbers until it equals 999.  For some reason the first number entered doesn't register and comes up at 0.  I know I've set it as 0 but thats to push the program into a loop.

```
counter = 0
equals = 0
while equals < 999:
    equals = equals + counter
    print(equals)
    if counter < 998:
        counter = eval(input("Enter numbers to equal 999"))
    else:
        print("number entered is equal or over 999")
```

Comment: Don't use `eval(input(...))` use `int(input(...))` instead

Comment: I tested it and it's working okay?

Comment: okay, for some reason it didn't seem to be working for me.  I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

It prints `0` in the first iteration because you `print(equals)` before reading it from the input. So:

```
counter = 0
equals = 0
while equals < 999:
    if counter < 998:
        counter = int(input("Enter numbers to equal 999"))
    else:
        print("number entered is equal or over 999")
    equals = equals + counter
    print(equals)
```